# Google Web Toolkit (GWT) + XPath

Tags: xml, gwt, xpath

I need to evaluate XPath query in GWT.
I haven't a server-side so I have to evaluate them in my GWT client-side application.

Which is the best XPath library for GWT?

Answer (score 3):

I found **totoe** (http://code.google.com/p/totoe/), a GWT library based on Sarissa (thank you Diogo!). It works like a charm!

For example:

```
String xml = "...";
Document document = new XmlParser().parse(xml, "xmlns:acme=\"http://www.acme.org\"");
Element root = document.getRoot();
List<Comment> comments = document.findByType(NodeType.COMMENT);
List<Node> products = document.selectNodes("//acme:products");
```

Answer (score 0):

dont know if its the best, or if its what you're looking for, but a quick search came up with this : http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/

Comment: Thank you but Sarissa is a ECMAScript, i'm looking for a GWT library.